# Representation of derivative of Taylor polynomial

Tags: functional-analysis, taylor-expansion

I should prove, that for any $|\alpha| < m$

$D^{\alpha}_x T^m_y u(x)  = T_y^{m-|\alpha|} D_x^{\alpha} u(x),$

where

$$T_y^mu(x) :=  \sum_{|\alpha| < m} \frac{1}{\alpha !} D^{\alpha} u(y) (x-y)^{\alpha}$$
is the Taylor polynomial. For multi-index it holds, that
 $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n),$ $x^{\alpha} = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i},$ $\alpha ! = \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha_i !,$ $|\alpha| = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i, $ and for derivative $D^{\alpha} u = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \right)^{\alpha_1 }\dots \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^{\alpha_n} u.$

Since $(x-y)^{\alpha}$ can be expressed in form $$\sum_{|\gamma|+|\beta| = |\alpha|} a^{\alpha}_{(\gamma,\beta)}x^{\gamma} y^{\beta},$$
where $a^{\alpha}_{(\gamma,\beta)}$ are some constants, I can get to

\begin{align*}
D^{\alpha}_x T^m_y u(x) &= \sum_{|\hat{\alpha}|< m } \frac{1}{\hat{\alpha}!} D^{\hat{\alpha}} u(y)  D_x^{\alpha}(x-y)^{\hat{\alpha}}\\
&= \sum_{|\hat{\alpha}|< m }  \frac{1}{\hat{\alpha}!} D^{\hat{\alpha}} u(y) \sum_{|\gamma| +|\beta| = |\hat{\alpha}|} a_{(\gamma,\beta)}^{\hat{\alpha}}y^{\beta} \frac{\gamma!}{(\gamma-\alpha)!}x^{\gamma-\alpha},
\end{align*}

but can't get much out of it. (Notice the hat notation above the running "index" $\hat{\alpha}$.)

This problem is from book "The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods" by Brenner & Scott. Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Just use $$D_x^{\alpha}(x-y)^{\beta} = \frac{\beta!}{(\beta-\alpha)!}(x-y)^{\beta-\alpha}$$ when $\alpha \leqslant \beta$ (and it's $0$ if $\alpha_k > \beta_k$ for some $k$).

Comment: Oh, thank you very much.